# What does the Android documentation on Wear Watch Faces in Ambeint mode mean?

Tags: android, wear-os

On the design specs given by Google:
https://developer.android.com/design/wear/watchfaces.html

It tells me that ambient can be grayscale, but then goes on to mention low-bit ambient and burn-in protection. Does the article mean that in low-bit ambient it must be black and white, or do I have to find out if the screen is OLED? Or is there another variable to detect if it needs to be black and white? Or is it always just black and white in ambient?

Answer (score 0):

https://www.reddit.com/r/AndroidWear/comments/2qb3ia/clarifying_ambient_modes_everything_you_could/

There are TWO different types of ambient mode, and the first mode is just standard ambient mode. Color faces should turn black and white with gray detailing here and there. 
The second is low-bit ambient mode. Google says not to use anti-aliasing in this mode and for the most part it will only have a pixel completely white, or off and black. Not even gray scale here, and color is not supposed to be used and seems to looks terrible.